# If a cell in Column 7 equals the value in another cell change to the value in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

The code below changes the value of any cell in column 7 whose value is equal to the value in AF14 and changes it to the value in AF15. I would like to add more criteria say if is AF16 then change to A17, if is AF17 then change to AF18 and so on.

Thanks in advance

```
Private Sub macro13()

Dim i As Integer
Dim WK As Worksheet
Dim rg As Range

Set WK = Sheet4
For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 7) = rg Then Cells(i, 7).Value = Range("AF15").Value
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Private Sub macro13()

Dim i As Integer
Dim WK As Worksheet
Dim rg As Range
Dim cell_arr(1 To 5, 1 To 2) As String

Set WK = ActiveSheet

' cell_arr(x,1) --> cell_arr(x,2)
cell_arr(1, 1) = "AF14": cell_arr(1, 2) = "AF15"
cell_arr(2, 1) = "AF16": cell_arr(2, 2) = "AF17"
cell_arr(3, 1) = "AF18": cell_arr(3, 2) = "AF19"
cell_arr(4, 1) = "AF20": cell_arr(4, 2) = "AF21"
cell_arr(5, 1) = "AF22": cell_arr(5, 2) = "AF23"

For k = 1 To UBound(cell_arr, 1)
    For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    
        If Cells(i, 7) = Range(cell_arr(k, 1)) Then
                Cells(i, 7).Value = Range(cell_arr(k, 2)).Value
        End If
    
    Next i
Next k

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear, I wonder two things:

- Why do you do this in a macro? Do you want that value only to be filled in at a certain event (like a button-click)?
- In case you don't need a macro, you might do this using either a bunch of nested `IF(...)` clauses, or you might opt for a combination of `HLookup()` (find a value somewhere inside a row) and `OffSet(-1,0)` (once you found a cell, take the one in the same row but in the column at the left).